# LWC: Making child cards grow with each other

Tags: lightning-web-components, lightning-experience, lightning-design-system, code

I'm very new to all of this, so apologize if this is obvious to others. I have four cards that I am using in a parent lwc. The content of each is different, but I want all of the cards to be the same height and grow to the same height if content is added to one card. What is the best way to accomplish this?

parent HTML

```html
<template>
    <div class="slds-grid slds-gutters_x-small slds-wrap">
        <div class="slds-col slds-large-size_1-of-2 slds-small-size_1-of-1">
             <c-card-1
                get-id-from-parent={recordId}
                object-api-name={objectApiName}>
            </c-card-1>
        </div>
    <div class="slds-col slds-large-size_1-of-2 slds-small-size_1-of-1">
            <c-card-2
            get-id-from-parent={recordId}
            object-api-name={objectApiName}>
            </c-card-2>
    </div>
    <div class="slds-col slds-large-size_1-of-2 slds-small-size_1-of-1">
            <c-card-3
            get-id-from-parent={recordId}
            object-api-name={objectApiName}
            ></c-card-3>
        </div>
        <div class="slds-col slds-large-size_1-of-2 slds-small-size_1-of-1">
        <c-card-4
            get-id-from-parent={recordId}
            object-api-name={objectApiName}>
        </c-card-4>  
        </div>
    </div>
    </template>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this the flex or grid CSS or even with lightning layout. The idea is to find out the tile with the max height and set that height to other tiles. This can be done with the help of the `renderedCallback` method.

Here is the code. Also live example link attached at the end.

**HTML**

```html
<template>
    <div class="slds-grid slds-gutters_x-small slds-wrap">
        <div class="tile slds-col slds-large-size_1-of-2 slds-small-size_1-of-1">
            <div class="content">
                Put your comonent here
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="tile slds-col slds-large-size_1-of-2 slds-small-size_1-of-1">
            <div class="content">
                Tile 1 - This is some content
                Tile 1 - This is some content
                Tile 1 - This is some content
                Tile 1 - This is some content
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="tile slds-col slds-large-size_1-of-2 slds-small-size_1-of-1">
            <div class="content">
                Tile 1 - This is some content
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="tile slds-col slds-large-size_1-of-2 slds-small-size_1-of-1">
            <div class="content">
                Tile 1 - This is some content
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</template>
```

**JS**

```js
import { LightningElement } from "lwc";

export default class MyComponent extends LightningElement {

  renderedCallback(){
    let tiles = this.template.querySelectorAll('.tile');
    let maxHeight = 0;
    tiles.forEach(tile => {
      const content = tile.querySelector('.content');
      const contentHeight = content.getBoundingClientRect().height;
        if (contentHeight > maxHeight) {
          maxHeight = contentHeight;
        }
    });

    // Apply the maximum height to all tiles
    tiles.forEach(tile => {
        const content = tile.querySelector('.content');
        content.style.minHeight = `${maxHeight}px`;
    });
  }
}
```

**CSS**

```css
.tile {
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    padding: 10px;
}
```

[Live example on the playground](https://app.lwc.studio/edit/ts1jjrgFXaI7pXimn4mX/src/app.html?p=stories)

Checkout my blog post on this [Create Uniform Tiles with Dynamic Content in LWC](https://www.forcetrails.com/2023/10/create-uniform-tiles-with-dynamic-content-lwc.html)

Comment: Would you have an example of how to implement this for child cards? I'm having trouble getting this to work for my case

Comment: @LaurenSweet just put your child component inside the div with the `tile` class and give it a class as content, and then add the renderedCallback code to your parent component.